# Using an sql stored procedure for a yes no output

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i have a database with

- *username varchar(10)*
- *usernumber varchar(10)*.

I would like to use a stored procedure so i can search the username and number together to return a simple 'yes' if they both match, or 'no' if they don't.

How would this be done in a stored procedure, i know there are easier ways but i need it in a stored procedure format.

Comment: i realize this is way off, I'm quite new to sql and have been doing this all day haha. it was something like this:

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.IsExistingUser
     @username varchar(10)
    ,@usernumber varchar(10)
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblUsers 
           WHERE username = @username AND usernumber = @usernumber) 
   SELECT 1
ELSE
   SELECT 0

GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this stored procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserCheck]
     @username varchar(10)
    ,@usernumber varchar(10)
AS
    SELECT (CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  tblUsers 
                        WHERE username=@username AND usernumber=@usernumber ) 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
            ELSE 'Yes' END)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just return a number from the stored procedure. 0 or 1.

If 1 then they match, if 0 they dont match

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedure] 
    @username varchar(10),
    @usernumber varchar(10)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if (Select Count(*) From YOURTABLE where username = @username and usernumber = @usernumber) > 0
    begin
        Select 1
    end
    else
    begin
        Select 0
    end

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
select case 
  (select id from usertable t where t.username = @username) = usernumber 
  then 
   1 
  else 
   0 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(usernumber) from tableX where unum = number
if you recieve the count > 0 then you have a row. Then return 1 or 0 or wat ever you want.